# Conditional ngRepeat based on dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to display a list based on which item is selected in a dropdown.

When I use the code below, I'm getting this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Any suggestions on how to do this right?

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="editProject.project.type" 
ng-options="project as project.type for project in editProject.options track by project.type">
</select>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="benefit in editProject.foods()">{{snack}}</li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('EditProjectCtrl', function () {

  var editProject = this;

 editProject.options = [
    {'type': 'Fruits'},
    {'type': 'Vegetables'},
    {'type': 'Desserts'}   
];

 editProject.snacks = function() {

  if(editProject.project.type == 'Fruits') {return [
    'Grapes',
    'Oranges',
    'Apples',
  ]}

  if(editProject.project.type == 'Vegetables') {return [
    'Broccoli',
    'Spinache',
    'Kale',
  ]}

  else {return [
  'Cookies',
  'Cake', 
  'Pie']}
};
```

Comment: `ng-model` of the select list is set to `editProject.project.type` but in the controller you are reading `editProject.projects.type` (notice the 's').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. There was a mismatch between the `ng-model` of the select element, and the conditions in the controller. I also replaced `benefit in editProject.foods()` with `snack in editProject.snacks()`:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="editProject.project" ng-options="project as project.type for project in editProject.options track by project.type"></select>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="snack in editProject.snacks()">{{snack}}</li>
</ul>
```

Because `editProject.project` is not defined until you select a *project*, you have to initialize it in the controller:

```
editProject.project = {};
```

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1o93cfu/4/)**